# How to parse wp_get_themes parent data in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, object, wordpress

I'm using `wp_get_themes` and getting data like

```
  'customizr-child' => 
  WP_Theme::__set_state(array(
     'theme_root' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wordpress/wp-content/themes',
     'headers' => 
    array (
      'Name' => 'customizr-Child',
      'ThemeURI' => '',
      'Description' => 'custom',
      'Author' => 'selva',
      'AuthorURI' => '',
      'Version' => '1.0.2',
      'Template' => 'customizr',
      'Status' => '',
      'Tags' => '',
      'TextDomain' => '',
      'DomainPath' => '',
    ),
     'headers_sanitized' => 
    array (
      'Name' => 'customizr-Child',
      'Version' => '1.0.2',
    ),
     'name_translated' => NULL,
     'errors' => NULL,
     'stylesheet' => 'customizr-child',
     'template' => 'customizr',
     'parent' => 
    WP_Theme::__set_state(array(
       'theme_root' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wordpress/wp-content/themes',
       'headers' => 
      array (
        'Name' => 'Customizr',
        'ThemeURI' => 'http://presscustomizr.com/customizr',
        'Description' => 'Navigate to Appearance, Customize. Design in live preview, save and enjoy a beautiful, fast and responsive website compatible with all browsers. For developers, Customizr offers a well documented and modular code, easy to extend with hooks.',
        'Author' => 'nikeo',
        'AuthorURI' => 'http://presscustomizr.com/',
        'Version' => '3.3.0',
        'Template' => '',
        'Status' => '',
        'Tags' => 'gray, white, light, blue, red, yellow, green, purple, orange, black, one-column, two-columns, three-columns, left-sidebar, right-sidebar, fluid-layout, responsive-layout, custom-menu, custom-colors, featured-images, full-width-template, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready, sticky-post, post-formats, rtl-language-support, editor-style',
        'TextDomain' => 'customizr',
        'DomainPath' => '',
      ),
       'headers_sanitized' => NULL,
       'name_translated' => NULL,
       'errors' => NULL,
       'stylesheet' => 'customizr',
       'template' => 'customizr',
       'parent' => NULL,
       'theme_root_uri' => NULL,
       'textdomain_loaded' => NULL,
       'cache_hash' => '9eaa4b1ecce2cdc9c89fb140e4460db2',
    )),
     'theme_root_uri' => NULL,
     'textdomain_loaded' => NULL,
     'cache_hash' => 'e7ee998a4907a798fdbabb0873cae622',
  )),
```

I need to get `parent` details . I can get following informations with help of wordpress documentation

```
Name' => 'customizr-Child',
      'ThemeURI' => '',
      'Description' => 'custom',
      'Author' => 'selva',
      'AuthorURI' => '',
      'Version' => '1.0.2',
      'Template' => 'customizr',
      'Status' => '',
      'Tags' => '',
      'TextDomain' => '',
      'DomainPath' => '',
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme
but I want `parent` data !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following things will give you that object

```
$theme= wp_get_theme('customizr-Child');
$them->parent()
```

more info refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Theme